# Numpy: particle coordinates into image

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of coordinates that represent some particles on a 5x5 plane. E.g.:

```
coords = [ [1.4, 3.2], [2.221, 4.313], [0.411, 4.3221] ]
```

I would like to obtain an image, say of size 64x64 where the pixels are black at the coordinates and white everywhere else.

Comment: That is a requirement (and a vague one at that), not a specific programming question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more advice and information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it nicely:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Coordinates
coords = [ [1.4, 3.2], [2.221, 4.313], [0.411, 4.3221] ]

# Make white 64x64 image, all pixels = 255
im = np.ones((64,64),dtype=np.uint8)*255

# Make each pixel at given coordinates black (0)
for c in coords:
    x,y = c
    im[round(y*64/5),round(x*64/5)] = 0

# Save result
Image.fromarray(im).save('result.png')
```

Note that Python takes the first index of an array as `y` and the second as `x`. Not also that I scaled up the size and added the red border around your image artificially just to show the extent of the image on Stack Overflow's white background.

[image]

---

If you wanted to animate it and make an animated GIF, you could use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import random

# Create a list of frames of the animation
frames = []

# Loop, making 30 frames
for f in range(30):

    # Make white 64x64 image, all pixels = 255
    im = np.ones((64,64),dtype=np.uint8)*255

    # Make 3 pixels at random coordinates black (0)
    for c in range(3):
        x,y = random.randint(0,63), random.randint(0,63)
        im[y,x] = 0

    # Append new frame to our list
    frames.append(Image.fromarray(im))

# Save result
frames[0].save('anim.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], duration=100, loop=0)
```

[image]

---

Note that you don't actually need to write any Python code to do this and you could just use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So just in Terminal:

```
 magick -size 64x64 xc:white -fill black \
        -draw "point 25,10"              \
        -draw "point 50,50"              \
        -draw "point 5,25"  result.png
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, Pillow, animated GIF, animation, particle, particles, image, image processing, coordinates.